# Ruby 1.9 Base64 encoding write to file error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, character-encoding, base64, ruby-1.9

I'm getting the following error:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x81" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

The below all worked in Ruby 1.8.7, so I think this has to do with how Ruby 1.9 handles encoding, but I'm not quite sure how to solve it.  I'm currently using Ruby 1.9.3.

> ```
>   decode_base64_content = Base64.decode64(content) 
>
>   File.open("index.txt", "w") do |f|
>     f.write(decode_base64_content)
>   end
> ```

Where content is something like:

```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```

that continues for ~3000 lines.

How do I resolve this conversion error?  The above snippet works but somewhere in the 3000 lines I think the base64 decode method uses an invalid encoding. Thanks!

Comment: It would be useful to know whether the exception is raised by the `Base64.decode64` call or by the `f.write` call.

Comment: The error is on the f.write call

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given that `"\x81"` is a control character, so it's not text of any means, you should open the file binary:

```
File.open("index.txt", "wb") do |f|
  f.write(decode_base64_content)
end
```

Comment: is "wb" an alias for "w:binary"?

Comment: Don't know about `"w:binary"`. The flags are the same as in the libc open call, it's a string among "r" (read), "rw" (read/write), "w" (write, truncating), "a" (write, appending), plus an optional "b" for binary mode.