# How to avoid getting UndefinedConversionError during decoding a file?

Tags: ruby, encoding, base64, encode

I have `somefile` which I want to encode using `base64`

```
File.open('data/somefile.edf').read.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>

base64_string = Base64.encode64(open("data/somefile.edf").to_a.join)
```

And then I want to decode that file

```
file = open('new_edf.edf', 'w') do |file| 
  file << Base64.decode64(base64_string)
end
```

But I get an error:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xE1" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
from (pry):22:in `write'
```

Comment: just out of curiosity ... did my solution help resolve the issue at all?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that by default the file is opened for writing in text mode.  To fix this, open the file using binary mode:

```
File.open('new_edf.edf', 'wb') { ... }
```

You can also check out this other question: [Ruby 1.9 Base64 encoding write to file error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127992/ruby-1-9-base64-encoding-write-to-file-error)

Comment: or fiile.binmode